# Why is my animation getting stuck in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm seeing some weird behavior with my CSS animations and was hoping someone could help out. I basically am using a select box to choose which `<ul>` should be displayed. However, if the user selects Value A, selects Value B, and then selects A again, the animation gets thrown into an infinite loop fading between A and B.

```
$('select#month').change(function(){
    var s = $('option:selected', this).val();

    $('#plan-wrapper ul.visible').addClass('scaleFadeOut').on('animationend', function(){
      $(this).removeClass('scaleFadeOut visible').addClass('hidden');

      $('#plan-wrapper ul#' + s).removeClass('hidden').addClass('scaleFadeIn').on('animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('scaleFadeIn').addClass('visible');
      });

    });
  });
```

I currently don't have this online anywhere, but I'll be setting up a staging site soon. I'll update this post with the link if I need to.

**EDIT:** As promised, here is a staging site link: https://lbc.labs.nichols-co.com/vision

Can I stop getting downvotes now?

Comment: Help us help you, provide a minimal working code example

Comment: @seemly got the staging site up. feel free to take a look now. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to /u/SirHound on reddit. He pointed out that I need to be calling `off()` to remove the event listeners. [Here is a link to his answer.](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/5nd3b2/why_is_my_animation_getting_stuck_in_a_loop/dcai57v/)